# How to add up all the tickets in an epic

Tags: jira, epics

Have you ever found yourself manually adding up the story points of all the tickets in an epic, only to realize that many of the tickets do not have an estimated sprint value?

Comment: Epics are "really big stories" that haven't been decomposed yet. Why are you assigning stories to future Sprints, or trying to retroactively determine how many story points some decomposed epic was worth? The "why" matters, because it seems like something you shouldn't be doing in the first place. If you have a use case there may be a better approach.

Comment: That's a great question. We are not assigning stories to future sprints (though I have seen that done as a way to prioritize the backlog). In this case, I think product owners are trying to figure out how much work is left in the roadmap (epic of epics).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bookmarklet will add up the sprint value of all estimated tickets in the epic, tell you how many tickets do not have an estimate, and how many tickets there are in the epic.

Add a bookmark on any page to your bookmarks bar, then right-click on it and select edit

1. Paste the JavaScript below in the URL field
2. Edit the title field to something like “epic total”
3. Test it on an epic page in Jira.

```
    javascript:{
      const elements = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('css-1lt331k'));
      const ticketEstimates = elements.map(el => el.innerHTML);
      let numOr0 = n => isNaN(n) ? 0 : n;
      const numericValues = ticketEstimates.map(val => numOr0(val));
      const sumOfAll = eval(numericValues.join('+'));
      alert('The total value of the estimates of all tickets in this epic is ' + sumOfAll + '\n' + 'The total number of tickets in this epic is ' + numericValues.length + '\n' + 'The number of unestimated tickets in this epic is ' + numericValues.filter(x => x === 0).length);
    }
```

The resulting alert looks like this:

[image: Alert popped up by the bookmarklet, giving the total of the estimates, the total number of tickets in the epic, and the number of unestimated tickets.]

Comment: I also considered adding a line of the script to insert the total value of the tickets into the story points field of the epic

Answer (score 0):

If this is a relatively infrequent one-off, one option would be:

1. Open the Epic
2. From the "Child issues" ellipsis menu, select "View in search" **NOTE: You can update this query as needed, for example to only show remaining work, etc**
3. Select "Export" > "Export Excel CSV" (use "my defaults" if you have story points shown, otherwise use "all fields")
4. Open the spreadsheet, highlight the column that show the Story Points, and the total story points will be shown as "Sum" on the bottom status bar.

If this is something that is done frequently enough that you need realtime data, there are a number of more complicated solutions on the Atlassian Community to resolve this using automations and/or custom fields.